# How to go up using __dirname in the folder hierarchy

Tags: express

My app structure is:

```
 /app
     /css
     /js
     ..
 /script
    /server.js
```

I'm trying to use __dirname to point to /app folder when using

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/app'));
```

I dont realy know what to search for in the web, please help.

Comment: Why the downvote ? I think this question is legitimate.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

if you're in server.js then you mean

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/../app'));
```

Comment: I am in express.js file and '/../' doesn't translate, it shows 'current_directory_path/../app' this as the result and cant find the file... any ideas why?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu, the same syntax is working in other places but it doesn't work inside express.js file.

Comment: and you have the same folder structure as the original question?

Comment: No, my directory structure is change, my problem is that '../../' the syntax that tells it that it should traverse back from current file path, doesn't translate and it is trying to find the file at 'drive:/desktop../../favicon.ico' the path mentioned here is a dummy and just conveys how it translates in actual environment.

Answer (score 23):

You can use [path](http://The%20path%20module%20provides%20utilities%20for%20working%20with%20file%20and%20directory%20paths.) module for that.

> The path module provides utilities for working with file and directory paths.

```
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '..', 'app')));
```

Comment: Please add short explanation to your answer.

Answer (score 1):

__dirname is just a string, you can do string manipulation on it.

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname.substring(0, __dirname.indexOf("\\routes") + '\app'));
```

I will be honest, I used it for a different purpose:

```
res.sendFile('./uploads/' + req.params.id + '/' + req.params.filename, {"root": __dirname.substring(0, __dirname.indexOf("\\routes"))});
```

So you may have to work with the / vs \ a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I did a simple solution , but it works. in your startup server script js
you can add the following:

```
var publicFolder = __dirname + '/public/';
config.public_folder = publicFolder;
```

Then whenever you need access to this folder else where in the code in sub folders or routes, you need to inject the public folder variable. and use it like this:

```
  res.sendFile(config.public_folder+'unsubscribed-success.html');
```